# What is behind the statue in majula

Tags: dark-souls-2

What exactly is behind the statue in majula? I haven't opened it yet because I don't want to be attacked.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you are asking? Can you be a bit more specific about which statue/where it is located. Perhaps include a screenshot?

Comment: Majid isn't a place in DS2... do you mean Majula? If so, what makes you think you'd be attacked? This is extremely unclear due to the place being asked about not existing. If you could update the question with more information, that would be very helpful.

Comment: I have edited the question to correct the location name. If you are referring to a different location, please correct it.

Comment: I'm so sorry I ment Majula.I was also taking about Rosabeth of Melfia. And l'm kind of a new to this game and have a weak character. But thank you Ben for your answer it was very helpful

Comment: Vemonus, you made it sound like I wouldn't be attacked but a group of troll things attacked me.How am i to kill all of them man?

Answer (score 5):

There are only 2 statues in this area, one is in Majula, the other in Things Betwixt (if you are playing SotFS)

Majula: This statue is [Rosabeth of Melfia](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Rosabeth+of+Melfia), and she blocks the entrance to the Shaded Woods. You will need to free her, if you want to progress through the game.

[image: Rosabeth Statue]

Things Betwixt: There is now a statue found in Things Betwixt, of an undead. This statue blocks the way to an Estus Shard. I'm not sure which one was moved, but I'd say it is one of the intended 12 needed to completely upgrade your Estus Flask (Which is redundant, because you can simply get them in ng+).

[image: Things Betwixt Statue]